# How can I add request headers such as "referer" to a link embedded in a document so the servers know the document info ( doi or something )?

Tags: links, doi, url

I'm working with some ways to track the actions that come from documents I
or others may write. Sometimes you see journals have things like "impact factor"
and online advertising has a lot of means to evaluate ad effectiveness. I wanted
to include a document identifier in a request header so that when someone clicks
on a link, maybe in the bibliography, that the server can determine which document
generated the user interest. However, I can't find anything about "request headers"
and the "header" term gets mixed up with page headers while the quote string returns
no results.  I can modify the embedded links with a document specific query sting but
the referer header seems better suited for this.

Thanks.
Edit: to clarify, I made a local url in a tex document,

> Blockquote
> However, many diseases relate
> to changed redox status. VKOR regenerating reducing agents ZZe
> http://127.0.0.1:9999/foo/doo.html

In another window, I open up a server socket with netcat and
get this output ( not the lack of a referer),

> `nc -l 9999
> GET /foo/doo.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:9999
> Connection: keep-alive
> sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90"
> sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
> DNT: 1
> Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
> Sec-Fetch-Site: none
> Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
> Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
> Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Comment: the referer header is set by the server hosting the document, you can't set it from within the document.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: yes in html you can do rel="noreferrer" to block the header being sent but you can't control its content (and in pdf I don't think you can even do that)

Comment: I guess maybe this is a pdf question rather than tex but just to clarify see my next post. Thanks

Comment: if the pdf with the link was just on the filesystem you won't get a referer you need to put it on a server with an IP address that it can report.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the issue. A server request generated in response to a link click can contain arbitrary headers created by the user agent. In this case, presumably clicking in the pdf viewer passes just the link and opens the system default browser with only that link. There may be no support for passing headers BUT that does not have to be the case as even headless chrome can be scripted ( puppeteer IIRC) to change headers. The point of the referer is to know the source of the interest which in this case would be a specific document regardless of where it happens to be.